# Mount dd image with multiple partitions

Tags: mount, image, dd, disk-volume

I have created an image of a disk using dd using the command dd if=/dev/sdb of=/jobs/image.dd. The SATA drive /dev/sdb has 3 partitions on it (one NTFS, two FAT32).

How do I mount the complete image with all its partitions in one go? I actually want to script this using Python but knowing how to do it is obviously the first step!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [kpartx](http://linux.die.net/man/8/kpartx) (from multipath-tools):

use losetup to get a /dev/loop? device, then use kpartx on it to create dev mappings for the partitions in the image file.

Comment: Great, kpartx worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Doing one partition at a time isn't too difficult.  Basically you use [losetup](http://linux.die.net/man/8/losetup) with the offset parameter.  Here is an [article](http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20:loop-mounting-partitions-from-a-disk-image/) that describes the steps, and here is [another](http://www.fluidsignal.com/en/publications/knowledge/20080923090245).

If you wanted to do all at once you would probably have to write a script that retrieved the partition table from the disk image, and then ran losetup several times to create several loop devices.  I am not aware of any tools that do this for you.